# How would a dualist respond to the following argument

Tags: advaita, upanishads, brahman, dvaita

How would a dualist respond to the following argument made by a nondualist?

> > Brahman cannot be the knower of anything. To know and to understand involve time. There is a before and an after. The former case involves ignorance because something is not known while the latter case involves knowledge. Brahman is beyond blemishes and so it cannot be in a state of ignorance. Since there is no knower and no thing to be known, the Brahman of the Upanishads must be non-dual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not ONE dualist understands Advaita.  Advaita is not a set of words about the nature of humans,Gods, Moksha etc. - it is a directly experienced wordless state.

Ramakrishna Paramahamsa expressed it best

https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/parables/1_files/1-56.html

> EGOISM: VANITY
> SANKARACHARYA AND HIS FOOLISH DISCIPLE
> THE great Sankaracharya had a foolish disciple who used to imitate his Master in all matters. Sankara uttered 'Sivoham' (I am Siva); the disciple also repeated 'Sivoham'. To correct his disciple's folly, Sankara one day, while passing by a smithy, took a potful of molten iron and swallowed it; and he asked that disciple also to do the same. Of course, the disciple could not imitate this act of his Master, and thence forward he left saying 'Sivoham'. (52)

There are numerous word-level counters to Advaita from Theistic schools that mean nothing.  Mandanaamisra is said to have refuted Buddhism by joining a Buddhist monastery and learning all their teachings before refuting them.- I haven't heard of ONE dualist who actually experienced Advaitic truth and claimed it was false AFTER that.

Ramana Maharishi explains the stages of achieving the highest Advaitic truth:

https://www.messagefrommasters.com/Enlightenment/Ramana_Samadhi.htm

Comment: @S K But is the non-dual experience the highest state, or is there a higher state than that?

Comment: I added more material.  That Advaita is the highest truth is confirmed by Buddhism (nirvana) and Muslim and Christian Mystic traditions  @debbie

Comment: @S K Thank you.